# Sorting a JSON array of hashes in descending based on Date

Tags: ruby, sorting, date

My model has a date attribute:

```
'date'              => { 'type' => 'date'    }
```

I am querying based on a `user_id` attribute and displaying the list of results, then I convert it into a JSON array to be returned in the route.

```
modelObj = Models::Persistence::ModelName.where(:user_id => user_id)
return modelObj.to_json
```

This gives me an array of hashes, each hash having a date attribute. How can I sort the hashes based on the date? I tried doing a date sort by converting it to `to_i` but that doesn't work. How can I do a descending sort based on the Date object?

I tried adding `.order(:date)` after `.where` so that I don't sort the JSON array. This gives me

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `__sort_option__' for :date:Symbol
```

What am I missing? `.order(date: :desc)` doesn't break but still returns the data in ascending order.

Comment: Why don't you sort the results when you query the database so they're in the proper order after using `to_json`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using the .where().order() but that returns it in ascending. Have a look at my edits.

Comment: It really sounds like you need to learn more about doing database queries. Retrieving data then sorting it is a waste of CPU. DBMs are MUCH more efficient. You don't say what ORM you're using but Active Record and Sequel are the big two for Ruby, and their documentation cover all this nicely. Also, it's not necessary to add "Edit" markers. We can see what you've edited if we want to look at the edit history. Instead, add your changes into your question in a logical, readable, manner and we'll figure it out.

Comment: Ah, where do I start?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the literal question,

```
array.sort_by { |item| -item['date'].to_time.to_i }
```

However, the points raised in comments are very valid - if you can sort it already in SQL, you should do so. (If you want to know about SQL, tag with DBMS. If you want to know about a specific ORM, tag with those instead.)

EDIT: Thanks, Cary - Indeed, OP wanted the reverse sort.

Comment: Or `array.sort_by { |item| item['date']  }.reverse` or `array.min_by(array.size) { |item| item['date'] }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I thought about using `reverse`; it uses more memory, but is more readable. `min_by` would only return the lowest value, rather than the descending list.

Comment: I included [Enumerable#min_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) for fun. As you see, it takes an argument in v2.2. Same for `max_by`, `max` and `min`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Huh, TIL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need this: 
            .order("date DESC").
use order after "where".
 the first param is your column name,and the second param "DESC" means descend,if you don't write the second param,ruby will do default ascend.
(I hope you can understand me...I'm not good at English..)